# understanding "action required" email from GCP, re: enable Cloud Build API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I use Firebase for my web apps, not Google Cloud Platform -- though I'm aware that behind the scenes, every Firebase project is also a GCP project.

I just received an email from GCP, saying (excerpted):

> [Action required]: Enable the Cloud Build API for your projects before April 20, 2020, to ensure Cloud Function is built and deployed correctly ... You must enable the Cloud Build API for your project(s) to ensure your Cloud Function is built and deployed correctly. Once you enable the API, you may incur charges if your Cloud Build, Container Registry, or Cloud Storage usage exceeds the free tier limits for these products.

**Does this impact the deployment or development process for Firebase at all?**  (e.g., right now I use `firebase deploy` )

As far as I can tell, the answer is no -- it just allows for a greater maximum build-time-per-day.  But the email didn't mention Firebase at all, so I want to be sure I understand any other implications well before April 20.

Comment: Can downvoter clarify so that I can edit?

Comment: Since firebase also use function this is why firebase - > functions - > cloud build

Comment: thanks - I understand that part, but my question is whether the change affects the deployment or development on the firebase end

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support to get an official statement. If they make a clear statement, it would be helpful if you post it back here as the answer. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: since this has gotten a couple of upvotes, I'll just mention that I sent an email to support, and I will indeed post back once they respond

Answer (score 6):

I had the same questions and got in touch with the firebase support team, here are my questions and the answers I received:

"Is that mandatory?"

> Only if you are going to deploy Cloud Functions in the future, already
>   deployed functions will not be affected.

"How do I know if my Cloud Build, Container Registry, or Cloud Storage usage will exceed the free tier limits for these products? is there any way how can check what I've been using so I'll be prepared?"

> Cloud Build provides a free tier where only usage above 120
>   build-minutes/day will be charged. When your usage is within the free
>   tier, you will not be charged for the Cloud Build portion of Cloud
>   Function deployments. See Cloud Build pricing for more information.
>   Similarly, Cloud Storage and Container Registry share a free tier
>   where only usage above 5GB-months will be charged. ( * Note : free
>   tier only limited to US regions - US-WEST1, US-CENTRAL1, and US-EAST1
>   and aggregated over all 3 regions )? For example, if you have a large
>   deployment that uses 100GB of storage, you will only be charged an
>   additional $2.47 for storage/month (based on these particular U.S.
>   regional storage prices). You can monitor your usage and see whether
>   you are getting close to hitting the free quotas.

"Lastly, what does all this stuff do for my app?  Why do I need to add this other features? If you were to sell me this, how would you present it for my use-case?"

> This is a best effort from Google to communicate information that is
>   necessary to the user’s continued use of the product or that is
>   considered a necessary legal update and keep customers away from
>   having future issues. Using Cloud Build, Container Registry and Cloud
>   Storage provides the following benefits: Detailed function build logs
>   will be available in the GCP Console, aiding in debugging and
>   increasing visibility. The ability to get build time that exceeds the
>   current build quota of 120 build-mins/day. The ability to view a built
>   container image for your function in Container Registry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- I'm still waiting on some clarification from support, but I appreciate the additional questions/answers, especially, "how would you pitch me this?", and the non-answer of "we wouldn't pitch it to you, because we can just impose it."  (Though, to be fair, the free tier is generous.)

Answer (score 1):

I received the following response from Firebase Support:

> You will not be able to use cloud functions if you do not enable the Cloud Build API after this date [April 20, 2020].

And, in a follow-up exchange:

> as far as I know in terms of deployment everything will be the same

So, my interpretation of those responses with respect to the **original question (will this affect the mechanics of *development* or *deployment*) is:**

- Deployment process: no change necessary
- Development process: no change necessary*

*if your build time exceeds 120 minutes per day, *and* you wish to avoid associated charges, you could voluntarily investigate changing your deployment/development process to reduce build minutes.

Thanks also to Fran for his answer, which sheds light on other aspects of the change.