# Do Firebase Cloud Functions require Billing to be enabled by April 20, 2020 because of the Cloud Build API?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

- [Firebase: Enable the Google Cloud Build API for your Cloud Functions project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60396232/6509751) & [understanding "action required" email from GCP, re: enable Cloud Build API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60382362/6509751) ask for something different and I understand what Cloud Build means for Firebase Functions as described in the following. I am asking about the billing requirement - if that is a thing. This is not clear from the notice.

### Cloud Functions & Cloud Build

I have received notice via email that I need to do the following for my Firebase project:

> [Action Required] Enable the Google Cloud Build API for your Cloud Functions project(s) before April 20, 2020

The message further explains that [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) will use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/), [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/), and [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) in the future in order to deploy code.

### Billing

Having received the notice, I followed the described steps:

> 1. Access the [Cloud Build API](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/AFnwnKWJL2Fzogr3jlEtsWoYocghZBRV5ebzFS68U_0Og3FiUJNeYgUIyNQemAAfApOkDE7GnUMopHoawR7i144wU21W6OCVXikFmnCBw2kX41iY86QBbBSQ0Y0x9ZMayut8VSRQqHvGzsfqte1OXLEkGoy_R6N_hO2VyzjAEyEfqkw965i13D7oqJoK50hLrgiWhEc0FenBDjXPddseWml8QKXijvA-eVbk7c8s12foaU-mFw) link in the Cloud Console.
> 2. Select your project from the drop-down menu.
> 3. Click **Continue** to enable the Cloud Build API for the project. A box will appear in the lower-left corner to confirm the API is enabled.

I visited the link and followed the steps and it fails: `This API cannot be enabled at the moment. You may lack appropriate permissions.`
Using the "Enable" button at [Cloud Build in the Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/cloudbuild.googleapis.com) for my Firebase project shows me:

> ### Billing required

---

Does this mean that Cloud Functions for Firebase now *require billing to be enabled*, i.e. the **Blaze plan**?

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support to get an official statement about billing. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I hope not -- that would be sneaky!  It would be great if you could get an official statement from support on this issue and post back.

Comment: It was the same thing with App Engine month ago. Many used only App Engine for free for dev/uat project, no credit card needed. But, when Cloud Build has been introduce, a credit card was required. No extra billing because there is 120 free build minutes per day and per billing account, but if there is a lot of build on lot of project in the same day, you will start to pay!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is **yes** (confirmed by support) and no.

---

If you want to deploy Cloud Functions after April 20, *you will have to set up a **billing account** in the GCP console*. This is because you need to pay extra for Cloud Build when exceeding the free quota.

---

However, you do *not* need to select the *Blaze plan* in Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can never trust google to be good for long.

Now they want to move you to paid plans to write cloud functions.

If would have been ok, but when you consider that even simple things like knowing the count of a collection in firebase/firestore will also require a paid billing plan as probably you want to use increment/decrement counter on database triggers, it's really messed up to see how such a database can be useful.

I think its time for developer to find some other avenues which are more honest.