# Getting error while enabling the Google Cloud Build API for my projects?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Before a few days i got mail.

> Enable the Cloud Build API for your projects before April 20, 2020, to
>   ensure Cloud Function is built and deployed correctly.

1. Access the Cloud Build API link in the Cloud Console.
2. Select your project from the drop-down menu.
3. Click Continue to enable the Cloud Build API for the project. A box will appear in the lower-left corner to confirm the API is enabled.

After click i getting following error for some permission

```
This API cannot be enabled at the moment. You may lack appropriate permissions.
```

[image: Error Image].

**So, which type of permission required i need to enable this service ?**

Comment: Do you have a billing account enabled?  I believe that's required.

Comment: right now  i not enabled billing account

Comment: As far as I know, the API change now requires billing, so you'll need to enable that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Firebase Cloud Functions require Billing to be enabled by April 20, 2020 because of the Cloud Build API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453949/do-firebase-cloud-functions-require-billing-to-be-enabled-by-april-20-2020-beca)

Comment: but currently i used only firebase databse and nothing else, and may be i don't need anything except firebase in future , for this ,is  api enabling  necessary ?

Comment: yes , but i cant find proper solution from documentation .

Comment: i setup my billing address but still this error is shown while enabling GCP

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specific permissions that a user needs to [enable APIs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_apis) for a GCP project are:

- serviceusage.services.enable
- servicemanagement.services.bind

If you are already the owner of your project, you shouldn't have to add the [roles/servicemanagement.serviceConsumer](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/access-control#roles) role to your account to enable an API.

You also need to [enable billing](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_billing) on the project before you can enable new APIs.

Comment: I tried many time but dont clearly underi how to add role and its permission

Comment: First thing I need you to do is check what permissions you currently have. Log into your main account and click on "IAM & Admin" in the Google Cloud Platform Console menu. You should find yourself on the "IAM" page. In the table on this page, find the account you are using, and let me know what it says in the "Role" column.

Comment: sorry for late, here my account (as my email)says "owner"

Comment: hey please guide me to complete this

Comment: Alright, next you should try running this command in your cloud shell.
 - gcloud services enable cloudbuild.googleapis.com - If there is an error, post the message here.

Answer (score 1):

The error I was getting

---

> This API cannot be enabled at the moment. You may lack appropriate
> permissions.

---

The issue for me was I have multiple google / gmail accounts and when I changed deploy location I had to logout and then log back in:

```
firebase logout
```

and then log back in

```
firebase login
```

This was followed by opening browser and then selecting the appropriate google user to deploy application with.